# How to add selected events to hundreds of Radiobuttons

Tags: c#, wpf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhR7L.png)
As shown in the figure, every five radiobuttons are placed in a stackpanel.What I want to achieve is When a radiobutton is clicked, the number on the chosen raduibutton is stored in the database in order. If there are Thousands of radiobuttons, It is inefficient to add events one by one.how can I do this quickly?

```
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">
                        <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,10,0" Style="{StaticResource radBase}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Name="a131"/>
                        <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,10,0" Style="{StaticResource radBase2}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="a132"/>
                        <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,10,0" Style="{StaticResource radBase3}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="a133"/>
                        <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,10,0" Style="{StaticResource radBase4}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="a134"/>
                        <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,10,0" Style="{StaticResource radBase5}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="a135"/>

                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1">
                        <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,10,0" Style="{StaticResource radBase}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Name="b131"/>
                        <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,10,0" Style="{StaticResource radBase2}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="b132"/>
                        <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,10,0" Style="{StaticResource radBase3}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="b133"/>
                        <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,10,0" Style="{StaticResource radBase4}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="b134"/>
                        <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,10,0" Style="{StaticResource radBase5}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="b135"/>

                    </StackPanel>



     if (a131.IsChecked == true) { all1 += "1"; }
            if (a132.IsChecked == true) { all1 += "2"; }
            if (a133.IsChecked == true) { all1 += "3"; }
            if (a134.IsChecked == true) { all1 += "4"; }
            if (a135.IsChecked == true) { all1 += "5"; }
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into fu(id,zuofen,youfen)values(@id,@left,@right)";
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int64);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@left", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@right", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50);

            cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = bb;

            cmd.Parameters["@left"].Value = all1;
            cmd.Parameters["@right"].Value = all2;
```

Comment: what you want is `one` event handler that `all` the controls are subscribed to.  in the event handler you can get the id of the control calling the handler

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: @ JohnB,kennyzx:I added the code

Comment: if you are talking about `thousands` of ui controls then i would be questioning the `design`. no ui should have hundreds of controls on the `one` page ( or at least rarely).  however if that is the situation then you may need to consider creating the controls `programmatically` in some sort of loop and there you can hook up the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you have many *almost* identical event handlers, the only difference is the id of the control, a131/b131 and maybe a141/b141 for the next row.

Since the rows (each with 5 `RadioButtons` on the left and 5 on the right) are the same, you can define a `UserControl` for a row.

So instead of having many *almost* identical event handlers, you need to define only one event handler, in the `UserControl`.

For the id value you used in the SQL command, I guess you are using it to tell which row is clicked. You can set the id value to each UserControl’s Tag property, so you can access the id value from the event handler.

Comment: This is exactly how I've solved this problem in the past, a good example is when teaching someone to use a calculator you have all of the numbers call the same event and just use the Tag on the button to pass the "Value" into the event handle.